# DNS Movement and Messed up CSS with IE

Tags: css

SO, this site was working fine in Internet Explorer before I moved DNS to godaddy. here is the site.. http://csdassociates.com/ ... any advice as to why this wont be aligning correctly anymore?

Does something happen when you move DNS, to the files, I cant understand. I had this working just fine 2 weeks ago and tested all CSS there and it seemed fine. Now, all of a sudden its like it doesnt read any of my CSS, but I can see it is reading it. No real big errors on that part. Is my css so bad It just doesnt work in IE?

Is my only solution to create a new stylesheet for IE....Or can I just add some touch up to my current CSS? If you check it on Chrome, it works smooth as can be. Could this be a problem with my Jquery? If you find this question not ok, please feel free to vote it down, I am desperate and looking for someone out there who wants to help me.

my jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/kA9Tt/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DOCTYPE is transitional when you want strict. This means that IE is in Quirks mode by default. Use this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Comment: tried this, still no luck, I must have changed something since I last tested this, maybe its my touchwipe js. I will try removing it and see what happens.

Comment: OK, so I realized I had added a comment above the DOCTYPE of myself as the author and once I removed that, all problems vanished. Total noob move but hey I learned something. Im giving you the answer because this is a good thing to know and lead me to fin out what my problem was. Thanks

Comment: No problem, I too have had my encounter with Quirks mode. Sorry I didn't notice the comment. I'll admit it, as soon as I saw IE in Quirks mode, I checked your DOCTYPE and didn't look back.

Answer (score 0):

DNS change has no effect on any particular file. Since your page is loading fine, your DNS is setup correctly.

If your page is loading fine on my browser (Firefox). Which version of IE are you using?

Btw, do not use relative path's like `css/960.css` when pasting code in JSFiddle, unless you have set a base href like

```
<base href="http://csdassociates.com/"/>
```

Comment: THanks for the heads up, first time I used Jsfiddle. Realized that it was working there and I noticed I had not copied my comment I added above the doctype, so overall my total mistake.